# Partition groups as list of matrices in Python and NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a NumPy Matrix of the form:

```
dummy = np.array([['A', 1, 1],
                  ['A', 1, 1],
                  ['B', 1, 1],
                  ['C', 1, 1],
                  ['F', 1, 1],
                  ['I', 1, 1],
                  ['I', 1, 1],
                  ['I', 1, 1],
                  ['J', 1, 1],
                  ['K', 1, 1],
                  ['L', 1, 1],
                  ['M', 1, 1]])
```

What I am attempting to produce is a list of NumPy Matrices, where there can only be *n* different variations of string value per Matrix such as:

Having *n* = 4:

```
[array([['A', '1', '1'],
        ['A', '1', '1'],
        ['B', '1', '1'],
        ['C', '1', '1'],
        ['F', '1', '1']], <= 4 different groups (A,B,C,F)
       dtype='|S1'),
 array([['I', '1', '1'],
        ['I', '1', '1'],
        ['I', '1', '1'],
        ['J', '1', '1'],
        ['K', '1', '1'],
        ['L', '1', '1']], <= 4 different groups (I,J,K,L)
       dtype='|S1'),
 array([['M', '1', '1']], <= only one but kept
       dtype='|S1')]
```

I have the following function which almost works..

```
def partition_by(x, groups):
    uniques = set([])
    p = []
    q = []
    for i in x:
        if len(uniques) < groups or i[0] in uniques:
           uniques.add(i[0])
           p.append(i.tolist())
    q.append(np.array(p))
    return q

partition_by(dummy, 4)
```

yields:

```
[array([['A', '1', '1'],
       ['A', '1', '1'],
       ['B', '1', '1'],
       ['C', '1', '1'],
       ['F', '1', '1']], 
      dtype='|S1')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def split_col_based(dummy, colID = 0, n=4):
    mask = dummy[1:,colID] != dummy[:-1,colID]
    interval_idx = n*(np.arange((mask.sum()+1)//n)+1)
    idx = np.searchsorted(mask.cumsum(), interval_idx)
    return np.split(dummy, idx+1, axis=0)
```

**Sample input, output**

1) Input array :

```
In [79]: dummy
Out[79]: 
array([['A', '1', '1'],
       ['A', '1', '1'],
       ['B', '1', '1'],
       ['C', '1', '1'],
       ['F', '1', '1'],
       ['I', '1', '1'],
       ['I', '1', '1'],
       ['I', '1', '1'],
       ['J', '1', '1'],
       ['K', '1', '1'],
       ['L', '1', '1'],
       ['M', '1', '1']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

2) Output with `n=4` :

```
In [80]: split_col_based(dummy, n=4)
Out[80]: 
[array([['A', '1', '1'],
        ['A', '1', '1'],
        ['B', '1', '1'],
        ['C', '1', '1'],
        ['F', '1', '1']], 
       dtype='|S1'), array([['I', '1', '1'],
        ['I', '1', '1'],
        ['I', '1', '1'],
        ['J', '1', '1'],
        ['K', '1', '1'],
        ['L', '1', '1']], 
       dtype='|S1'), array([['M', '1', '1']], 
       dtype='|S1')]
```

3) Output with `n=5` :

```
In [81]: split_col_based(dummy, n=5)
Out[81]: 
[array([['A', '1', '1'],
        ['A', '1', '1'],
        ['B', '1', '1'],
        ['C', '1', '1'],
        ['F', '1', '1'],
        ['I', '1', '1'],
        ['I', '1', '1'],
        ['I', '1', '1']], 
       dtype='|S1'), array([['J', '1', '1'],
        ['K', '1', '1'],
        ['L', '1', '1'],
        ['M', '1', '1']], 
       dtype='|S1')]
```

4) Output with `n=2` :

```
In [84]: split_col_based(dummy, n=2)
Out[84]: 
[array([['A', '1', '1'],
        ['A', '1', '1'],
        ['B', '1', '1']], 
       dtype='|S1'), array([['C', '1', '1'],
        ['F', '1', '1']], 
       dtype='|S1'), array([['I', '1', '1'],
        ['I', '1', '1'],
        ['I', '1', '1'],
        ['J', '1', '1']], 
       dtype='|S1'), array([['K', '1', '1'],
        ['L', '1', '1']], 
       dtype='|S1'), array([['M', '1', '1']], 
       dtype='|S1')]
```

Comment: Thats awesome.. thank you sir.. could the function be adapted to where the string does not be at index 0.. for example [[1, 'A', 1], [1, 'A', 1], [1, 'B', 1], ...]] here it is at index 1. How can I pass the index in as an argument?

Comment: @adebesin Edited. Use `colID` input param : `colID = 1`.